# ConnectionAbortedError - if Celery stopped/failed or Redis is not started. How do I catch/except this error/

Tags: django, redis, celery

I have a Celery task that works with Redis:

```
@app.task(bind=True, name='task_a', max_retries=4, soft_time_limit_exception=300)
def task_a(self, a, b):
    try:
        # some code here
    except Exception as e:
        raise self.retry(exc=e, countdown=exponential_backoff(self))


def exponential_backoff(task_self):
    minutes = task_self.default_retry_delay / 60
    rand = random.uniform(minutes, minutes * 1.5)
    return int(rand ** task_self.request.retries) * 60
```

I have the following issue:

If Redis is not working or celery workers are stopped/failed, the code is 'waiting' than continue the execution of code.

If I put `try except block` inside the task, or the task called inside `try except`, it cathches nothing, I get a ConnectionAbortedError.

What I want in this cases, is to catch this specific errors and do other operations, or ignore without calling retry.

---

`@Pavel Minenkov` answer suggest to use sentry.io, but the issue is that I don't know were to catch it.

---

See Traceback:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49301)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 796, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonVENV\DjangoDev\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 86, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonVENV\DjangoDev\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 154, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "D:\DevEnv\Python\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Is your host machine Windows? Redis is running on localhost?

Comment: yes for development, but I also have a remote server with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Suppose some network problem

Comment: @PavelMinenkov; I know what is triggering the error, I just wanted to catch it to trigger a backup option. The thing is that the error is reported in an external lib/package (probably called by celery), and don't know how to catch it

Comment: According to call stack, the most early exception is `ConnectionAbortedError`

Comment: Then after raised `ConnectionAbortedError ` there is sequence of errors, so you should try catch mediated behaviour. Try check `self.status is None`, apparently wsgi wrap low level socket operation and hide internal exceptions

Answer (score 1):

First of all implement monitoring system. I like Sentry: https://sentry.io/welcome/ It is free for 1 user

```
from raven import Client
...
@app.task(bind=True, name='task_a', max_retries=4, soft_time_limit_exception=300)
def task_a(self, a, b):
    sentry = Client(dsn=<your>)
    with sentry.capture_exceptions():
        # some code here
```

Then you will be able found out what Exception(s) are raises, then you will able to workaround the issue